# Show that $\lambda_j(Q'_nA_nQ_n)-\lambda_j(A_n)\to 0 \quad \text{as}\quad n\to \infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $(A_n),(Q_n)$ be sequences of $k\times k$ real matrices. Moreover suppose that $(A_n)$ is symmetric and bounded, and that $Q_nQ'_n\to I_k$ as $n\to \infty$, where convergence is with respect to the Frobenius norm. Am trying to show that

$$\lambda_j(Q'_nA_nQ_n)-\lambda_j(A_n)\to 0 \quad \text{as}\quad n\to \infty,$$

where $\lambda_j$ denotes the $j$th largest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix. I did the following:

If $A,B$ are $k\times k$ positive semi-definite matrices with $A$ non-singular then

$$\|A^{1/2}-B^{1/2}\|\leq k^{3/2}\|A^{1/2}\|\|A-B\|$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Frobenius norm. (see Horn and Johnson (1990) *Matrix analysis* p.411). Therefore

$$(Q_{n}Q'_{n})^{1/2}\to I_k$$

Then from the continuity of eigenvalues on the space of real symmetric matrices (which can be shown using Weyl's inequalities for example) we get

$$\lambda_j(Q'_nA_nQ_n)-\lambda_j(A_{n})=\lambda_j((Q_{n}Q'_{n})^{1/2}A_n(Q_{n}Q'_{n})^{1/2})-\lambda_j(A_{n})\to 0$$

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Looks good to me if you are doing research work. If this is an exercise, however, you may need to explain why $(QQ_n')^{1/2}A_n(QQ_n')^{1/2}-A_n\to0$ implies that $\lambda_j(QQ_n')^{1/2}A_n(QQ_n')^{1/2})-\lambda_j(A_n)\to0$. Or more abstractly, why $B_n-A_n\to0$ implies that $\lambda_j(B_n)-\lambda_j(A_n)\to0$. One may deal with this by using Weyl's inequality or by using the uniform continuity of $\lambda_j$ on a compact set.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you for your feedback! Indeed the continuity of eigenvalues for Hermitian matrices can be shown using Weyl's inequalities. I will add this to my post.